# The component metadata could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method is failed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have developed a project in **Visual Studio 2015** and initially `TargetDeploymentVersion` was set to **2014**.

Later we realized this project also needs to be deployed on **SQL Server 2012**.

So, we changed `TargetDeploymentVersion` to **2012**, build the project, and deployed ***.ispac*** on **SQL Server Integration Services 2012**. The deployment went well.

Please note, we kept `Run64bitRunTime=False`.

But during validation I started receiving these component metadata could not be upgraded messages.

Following is a printout of the error:

[image]

Please, someone, help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Cause:

This is a Component Mismatch Exception.

The reason for this error is that the component was developed with a ***higher*** version of **SQL Server Integration Services**.

The server or workstation on which you are running or opening the **SQL Server Integration Services** ***Package*** contains an ***older*** version installed.

Since the downgrade of the component is not allowed, the ***Upgrade Process*** is triggered.

Unfortunately, the ***Upgrade Process*** was unsuccessful in reaching the goal.

### Solution:

To fix this error, it is necessary to change the `TargetServerVersion` parameter to ***SQL Server 2012*** in the **SQL Server Integration Services 2012** project.

[image: TargetServerVersion]

Right-click the project in the **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties**.

To display the `TargetServerVersion` option, go to **Configuration** properties and then **General**.

Deploy the entire project again, and this error will be resolved.

I hope this solution helps others who have this same error.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!